# cb is not a function in hapi-auth-jwt2 - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, restful-authentication, hapi.js

I'm following [this](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-hapijs/) tutorial to implement `jwt authentication` in `hapijs v17.2`.

I did everything according to the tutorial, but the following error is driving me crazy, even debugging didn't make any change.

**error**

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
    TypeError: cb is not a function
    at Object.secretProvider [as key] (C:\Users\user\WebstormProjects\hapi-blog\node_modules\jwks-rsa\lib\integrations\hapi.js:30:14)
    at Object.authenticate (C:\Users\user\WebstormProjects\hapi-blog\node_modules\hapi-auth-jwt2\lib\index.js:123:87)
    at module.exports.internals.Manager.execute (C:\Users\user\WebstormProjects\hapi-blog\node_modules\hapi\lib\toolkit.js:35:106)
    at module.exports.internals.Auth._authenticate (C:\Users\user\WebstormProjects\hapi-blog\node_modules\hapi\lib\auth.js:242:58)
    at authenticate (C:\Users\user\WebstormProjects\hapi-blog\node_modules\hapi\lib\auth.js:217:21)
    at module.exports.internals.Request._lifecycle (C:\Users\user\WebstormProjects\hapi-blog\node_modules\hapi\lib\request.js:261:62)
    at <anonymous>
```

**app.js**

```
const hapi = require('hapi');
const mongoose = require('./db');
const hapi_auth_jwt = require('hapi-auth-jwt2');
const jwksa_rsa = require('jwks-rsa');
const dog_controller = require('./controllers/dog');

const server = new hapi.Server({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4200
});

const validate_user = (decoded, request, callback) => {
    console.log('Decoded', decoded);
    if (decoded && decoded.sub) {
        return callback(null, true, {});
    }

    return callback(null, true, {});
};

const register_routes = () => {
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/dogs',
        options: {
            handler: dog_controller.list,
            auth: false
        }
    });

    // Test
    server.route({
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/a',
        options: {
            handler: (req, h) => {
                return h.response({message: req.params.a});
            },
            auth: false
        }
    });

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/dogs/{id}',
        options: {
            handler: dog_controller.get
        }
    });

    server.route({
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/dogs',
        options: {
            handler: dog_controller.create
        }
    });

    server.route({
        method: 'PUT',
        path: '/dogs/{id}',
        handler: dog_controller.update
    });

    server.route({
        method: 'DELETE',
        path: '/dogs/{id}',
        handler: dog_controller.remove
    });
};

const init = async () => {
    await server.register(hapi_auth_jwt);

    server.auth.strategy('jwt', 'jwt', {
        key: jwksa_rsa.hapiJwt2Key({
            cache: true,
            rateLimit: true,
            jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
            // YOUR-AUTH0-DOMAIN name e.g https://prosper.auth0.com
            jwksUri: 'https://mrvar.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json'
        }),
        verifyOptions: {
            audience: 'https://mrvar.auth0.com/api/v2/',
            issuer: 'https://mrvar.auth0.com',
            algorithm: ['RS256']
        },
        validate: validate_user
    });

    server.auth.default('jwt');

    // Register routes
    register_routes();

    // Start server
    await server.start();

    return server;
};

init().then(server => {
    console.log('Server running at: ', server.info.uri);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

When I make a request to routes with `auth: false`, the handler works properly then I get the expected result, but requests to routes without `auth` return the following json :

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "An internal server error occurred"
}
```

**More info:**

node version:     8.9.4

npm version:      5.6.0

hapi version:     17.2.0

hapi-auth-jwt2:   github:salzhrani/hapi-auth-jwt2#v-17

jwks-rsa:         1.2.1

mongoose:         5.0.6

nodemon:          1.15.0

Comment: are you still facing the issue, and did you checked mine latest answer?

Answer (score 5):

## Both libraries has support for hapi v.17

I also faced this issue, but surprisingly both libraries has support for hapi v.17, but all documentation is based on old versions or didn't use this combination ;)

### How to use it

There are few things that has to be changed then using hapijs v.17

#### Verify that you're using libraries versions which support hapijs 17:

- `"jwks-rsa": "^1.3.0",`
- `"hapi-auth-jwt2": "^8.0.0",`

#### Use `hapiJwt2KeyAsync` instead of `hapiJwt2Key`.

Information about this new async method is hidden in [node-jwks-rsa package documentation](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa/tree/master/examples/hapi-demo)

#### `validate` function has now new contract

Please change your existing `validate` function to below type:

```
async (decoded: any, request: hapi.Request): {isValid: boolean, credentials: {}}
```

---

### Working example (with handled passing scopes)

```
const validateUser = async (decoded, request) => {
    if (decoded && decoded.sub) {
        return decoded.scope
            ? {
                isValid: true,
                credentials: {
                    scope: decoded.scope.split(' ')
                }
            }
            : { isValid: true };
    }

    return { isValid: false };
};

server.auth.strategy('jwt', 'jwt', {
    complete: true,
    key: jwksRsa.hapiJwt2KeyAsync({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: env.auth.jwksUri
    }),
    verifyOptions: {
        audience: '/admin',
        issuer: env.auth.issuer,
        algorithms: ['RS256']
    },
    validate: validateUser
});
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me.  The important changes I needed to make were to add "complete: true" and use hapiJwt2KeyAsync.

Answer (score 4):

The validate function changed in hapi@17 to not have a callback function. Based on your example it should now look something like this:

```
const validate = async (decoded, request) => {
  if (decoded && decoded.sub) {
     return { isValid: true };
  }
  return { isValid: false };
};
```

Part of the returned object can also include `credentials` which would represent the user that is authenticated and you can also do a scope as part of the credentials.

Then if you want to you can access the credentials as part of the `request` object like `request.auth.credentials`

Comment: Although I used your example, the error is still persistent.

Comment: Sorry while my answer is valid as validate does not have callbacks that is not the issue. `jwksa_rsa` is expecting a callback but `hapi-auth-jwt2` doesn't send a callback to the `key` function anymore. The `jwksa_rsa` hapi code hasn't been updated for hapi 17

Comment: @HoomanL your issue can be fixed with this PR: https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa/pull/34